# Devuan for Raspberry Pi 2 Username and Password?

Tags: devuan

I've just imaged an SD card for Raspberry Pi 2 using the latest devuan image, however I can't find anywhere that has the default username and password for the image.

I've tried pi and raspberry, root and root, devuan and devuan, root and 123456 - does anyone have any suggestions or know the answer?

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi flavoured corner of the Stack Exchange network. Thanks for raising this question as it made me aware that someone HAS rolled a Devian RPi distribution! _I currently run Debian/Raspian on various machine (PCs, RPi) and have been sticking on Wheezy on my main machine though others are running Jessie with sysv init and the systemd-shim in place {together with a `/etc/apt/preferences.d/local-pin-init`containing `Package: systemd-sysv \n
Pin: release o=Debian \n
Pin-Priority: -1 \n` }_ I think this can be the first tag:devuan question - I hope we get more...!

Comment: @SlySven I'm very glad to have raised your awareness of this. To be honest I'd forgotten that devuan even existed until yesterday and then immediately setup an RPi 2 & 3 with their image.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apologies, I've just found the answer: root and toor.

From [http://wiki.friendsofdevuan.org](http://wiki.friendsofdevuan.org/doku.php/rpi):

> SSH and root login is enabled: user 'root', password 'toor'